# Adding Constraint programmatically swift

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

Please i need help with the below, i just start learning how to design interface programmatically, after few tutorials i wanted to try something, then i got stucked

**I am trying to achieve the below image**

[image: Desired output]

**but this is what i got**

[image: not what i want]

this is my code below

```
class FeedsCell: UICollectionViewCell{

override init(frame: CGRect){
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setupViews()
}

let thumNailImageView : UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    return imageView
}()

let sourceName:UILabel = {
  let srcLabel = UILabel()
    srcLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple
    srcLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return srcLabel
}()

let separatorView: UIView = {
   let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    return view
}()

func setupViews(){
    addSubview(thumNailImageView)
    addSubview(separatorView)
    addSubview(sourceName)

    addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|-16-[v0(194)]", views: thumNailImageView)

    addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:|-16-[v0]-16-[v1(1)]|", views: thumNailImageView, separatorView)

    addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|[v0]|", views: separatorView)



    //left Constriants
    addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: sourceName, attribute: .left, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: thumNailImageView, attribute: .right, multiplier: 1, constant: 8))

    //Right constraints
    addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: sourceName, attribute: .right, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: thumNailImageView, attribute: .right, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))

    addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|-8-[v0]-8-|", views: sourceName)
    addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:|-8-[v0(20)]", views: sourceName)

}

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}


extension UIView{
    func addConstraintsWithFormat(format: String, views: UIView...){

        var viewDictionary = [String: UIView]()
        for(index, view) in views.enumerated(){
            let key = "v\(index)"
            view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            viewDictionary[key] = view
        }


    addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: format, options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: viewDictionary))
    }
}
```

Comment: Slightly OT, but have you considered using the newer anchors API? I find it much easier to do this kind of stuff. Might be a simple error (which I don't see at first glance) in the above would go away. E.g. `sourceName.leftAnchor.constrainEqualToAnchor(thumNailImageView.rightAnchor).isActive = true`

Comment: @TravisGriggs A much better solution is to use xibs & storyboards.

Comment: @Sulthan i can use xibs and storyboard to achieve it, but am trying to do this programmatically, cus i will be performing some functionalities

Comment: @TravisGriggs i am looking into the anchor api, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to solve the issue using SnapKit, to achieve the image did something like this

```
let screenFrame = UIScreen.main.bounds

    thumNailImageView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.width.equalTo(194)
        make.top.equalTo(contentView).offset(20)
        make.left.equalTo(contentView).offset(20)
        make.bottom.equalTo(contentView).offset(-20)
    }

    sourceName.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.width.equalTo(screenFrame.width/2 - 40 )
        make.height.equalTo(20)
        make.top.equalTo(contentView).offset(20)
        make.left.equalTo(contentView).offset(screenFrame.width/2 + 20 )
    }

    postTitle.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.width.equalTo(screenFrame.width/2 - 40 )
        make.height.equalTo(30)
        make.top.equalTo(sourceName).offset(30)
        make.left.equalTo(contentView).offset(screenFrame.width/2 + 20 )
    }

    timeStamp.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.width.equalTo(screenFrame.width/2 - 40 )
        make.height.equalTo(10)
        make.top.equalTo(postTitle).offset(40)
        make.left.equalTo(contentView).offset(screenFrame.width/2 + 20 )
    }

    postContent.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.width.equalTo(screenFrame.width/2 - 40 )
        make.height.equalTo(60)
        make.top.equalTo(timeStamp).offset(20)
        make.left.equalTo(contentView).offset(screenFrame.width/2 + 20 )
    }
```